# Контент сайта и его фон

Tags: html

Я новичок в верстке,так что помидорами не кидайтесь) Как сделаны такие сайты, что слева и справа находится очень длинный фон, а по середине сам контент сайта причем при прокрутки он уходит далеко в низ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фон добавляется к тегу `body`, а сам контент помещается в отдельный элемент. Где хранится все

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

div {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>Здесь ваш контент</div>
```

Comment: Т.е. я вас правильно понял, создается `body` c бэкграундом картинки,а после в `body` создаем `div` где уже растягиваем свой цвет\картинку, и там пишем контент?

Comment: ну `body` это обязательный тег для любой странички

Comment: @Анкор картинка прописывается `body`, через `background-image`, например

Comment: А если по мимо картинки в `body` еще нужно добавить картинку по середине, как показано на скриншоте,это в `div-e` делать?

Comment: @Анкор все верно